# Unit Testing using Microsoft Fakes - Skipping a function

Tags: c#, unit-testing, ref, microsoft-fakes, shim

SO , here i am writing unit test cases for my project. I am stuck at one point where i am having a function call that has ref parameter. Example :-

**`public decimal addToSubtractFromCheckAmount(decimal dChkAmt,ref ICharge oCharge, bool blnAddTo, bool blnIncludeRBL)`**

I am writing a test case of a function that calls the above function (addToSubtractFromCheckAmount) and i want to skip it and provide my custom return value.

**
using(ShimsContext.Create())

```
ShimClassName.AllInstances.addToSubtractFromCheckAmountDecimalIChargeBooleanBoolean
= (a, b, c, d, e) => new decimal(20);
```

**
This works when i do not pass a ref parameter, but when i gave ICharge interface a ref keyword, the function disappears from my Unit Test case class metadata, and when i build the project i get this error
**

> Error 101 Service.Fakes.ShimClassName.AllInstances' does not contain a
>   definition for
>   'addToSubtractFromCheckAmountDecimalIChargeBooleanBoolean'

**
Many websites talk about SHIMMING functions that has string ref parameters, but not of interfaces, Collections, etc.
For example

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26918525/using-microsoft-fakes-to-shim-a-method-with-generic-list-parameters
>   How did this guy even get the function in AllInstances when his function has a ref parameter.

I am stuck on this for some time now. Can someone help? Please let me know if you guys need more info, Thanks.

Comment: Method name is in a cammel case. It is bad practice. It is recommended to follow c# code conventions.

Comment: That's fine, i am following proper coding practices in my main project. This is just a test case in a test project.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not hung up on using the Fakes, you could consider using NSubstitute. I've been hapilly using NSubstitute and Moq in my .NET projects. It will go something like this:

```
//Create:
var chargeSubstitute= Substitute.For<ICharge>();

//Set a return value:
chargeSubstitute.DoSomething(whatever).Returns(resultYouWantToUseInTest);
```

Now your test can look like:

```
var actual = something.addToSubtractFromCheckAmount(testValue,ref chargeSubstitute, true, true);
```

and you can test that against your expected value. See [NSubstitue](http://nsubstitute.github.io/) or [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4)

Comment: As its my company project, we do not have permission to use anything else, other than Microsoft Fakes. That's a bummer. Thanks Spike, your answer looks great but i do not think i will be able to use it.

Answer (score 0):

From my testing, it looks like this will only work if you move the ref parameter to the end of the argument list. I did a test with an interface ref parameter between two int parameters and it didn't appear in the AllInstances properties. However, when I moved the ref parameter to the end, it showed up.

If you do that, you should see a shim delegate named `addToSubtractFromCheckAmountDecimalBooleanBooleanIChargeRef`.

Another thing to keep in mind is that you can't use ref parameters with a lambda, so you'll need to create a function and assign that to the delegate. Something like this:

```
decimal mockedFunction(ClassName instance, decimal dChkAmt, bool blnAddTo, bool blnIncludeRBL, ref ICharge oCharge)
{
    // ... assign oCharge?
    return 20m;
}

[TestMethod]
public void MyTest()
{
    using (ShimsContext.Create())
    {
        ShimClassName.AllInstances.addToSubtractFromCheckAmountDecimalBooleanBooleanIChargeRef
            = mockedFunction;

        // ...continue with test
    }
}
```